# handlebar call a registerHelper in js file

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-blaze

I am using handlebar.js and have a function like this(it is located in client/dashboard/globalHelper.js):

```
Template.registerHelper('getLanguageValue', function(key) {

  return ....

});
```

I know if I want to use it in html file is like this:

```
{{getLanguageValue "dashboard"}}
```

But right now I want to call this function in another js file :

```
 var value= getLanguageValue("dashboard");
```

how does it possible?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
Blaze._globalHelpers.getLanguageValue("key");
```